# Checking the integrity of TAR files for backup

Tags: backup, tar, file-transfer, hashsum

I want make a backup of my Home directory and I've read a good method is to use the `tar` tool, and I think it suits me well since all I need to do is create a `.tar` of every folder in the Home directory (`Desktop.tar`, `Documents.tar`, etc) and then transfer if to the External Hard Drive (EHD).

One of my concerns, though, is making sure the files that gets copied to the EHD are not corrupted in the process. So I'm was thinking to follow this procedure to verify the integrity of my data (I will use the `Desktop` directory as example, but it is exactly the same for every other folder):

1. Use `tar` and create `Desktop.tar` **inside** my computer.
2. Calculate `md5` and `sha-2` hashes for `Desktop.tar`.
3. Move `Desktop.tar` to the EHD, which, let's say, is called `backup`.
4. Calculate `md5` and `sha-2` hashes for `backup/Desktop.tar` and verify they are the same as the ones calculated in the second step.

**So my questions are:**

1. Is this a good procedure to verify the data on my backup has not been corrupted in the transfer?
2. I know the tool used to calculate the `md5` hash is `md5sum`, but I'm not really sure what tool to use to calculate the `sha-2` hash function. So should I use `sha224sum`, `sha256sum`, `sha384sum` or `sha512sum`?

Comment: A single SHA-256 hash of each file is guaranteed to detect accidental corruption.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using both md5 and a short sha-2 gives you more certainty then using sha512sum alone.

Your method is in principle ok, but you can make the checking much easier by redirecting the output of `sha512sum *.tar` to a file `sums` and copy that to the destination machine as well.

Then do:

```
sha512sum -c sums
```

on the destination machine and it generates the sha512sum for each file mentioned in `sums` and checks it against the hash in the file

Comment: That looks simpler. Just one question: should I manually copy the output of the hash generator to the file or there is a command to do it?

Comment: @CarlRojas just redirect the ouput: `sha512sum *.tar > sums` or use tee if you want to see the output as well: `sha512sum *.tar | tee sums`

Answer (score 0):

Computing and verifying cryptographic checksums is a good method to detect changed file content, e.g. due to hard disk errors.

Like many cryptographic hash functions [SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) comes as a family of variants that differ in the digest size and initial values.

Since the probability to get a hash collision due to (random) bit errors is very low - even with MD5, you don't really have to 'upgrade' to SHA-2.

You would prefer SHA-2 over MD5 to protect against an attacker that deliberately tries to design a file that yields a collision. And with SHA-2 a larger digest size (i.e. 512 bits) would give you more head room against future attacks (at the cost of computation speed).